# npm, nodejs, package.json, Module version mismatch. Expected 48, got 51

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm using below `package.json` in my node project and when i run 
`npm test`, it gives the below error

> Module version mismatch. Expected 48, got 51

```
{
  "name": "f-api",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "Description": "F",
  "author": "F",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "start_supervise": "supervisor ./bin/www",
    "test": "mocha --recursive --timeout 10000"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "=1.0.2",
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "config": "^1.24.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "jwt-simple": "^0.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "nodemailer": "=2.7.2",
    "nodemailer-smtp-transport": "^2.7.2",
    "pg-promise": "^3.2.3",
    "sequelize": "^3.29.0",
    "sequelize-cli": "^2.1.0",
    "supervisor": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-http": "^3.0.0",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "nodemailer-stub": "^1.0.1",
    "should": "^11.1.2",
    "supertest": "^2.0.1"
  }
}
```

I think it's some incompatibility of versions, i'm bit new to `node, npm` and versions syntax like `^, ~, =`

I get the following out put in gitlab runner, docker executor

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.11.1 (a67a225)
  on gitlab-runner-b-ubuntuvm (1ffe18b1)
Using Docker executor with image node:6.10.0 ...
Starting service postgres:latest ...
Pulling docker image postgres:latest ...
Waiting for services to be up and running...
Pulling docker image node:6.10.0 ...
Running on runner-1ffe18b1-project-6-concurrent-0 via ubuntu...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/f/f-api'...
Checking out bcf3e283 as development...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Downloading artifacts for build:linux (495)...
Downloading artifacts from coordinator... ok        id=495 responseStatus=200 OK token=hXK-foh8
Checking cache for test:linux/development...
Successfully extracted cache
$ ./node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate --env=continuous_integration

Sequelize [Node: 6.10.0, CLI: 2.5.1, ORM: 3.30.2]

Loaded configuration file "config_tmp.json".
== 20170120101655-createUserTable: migrating =======
== 20170120101655-createUserTable: migrated (0.031s)
== 20170120111051-addPasswordDigestToUsers: migrating =======
== 20170120111051-addPasswordDigestToUsers: migrated (0.026s)
== 20170226151953-update-users: migrating =======
== 20170226151953-update-users: migrated (0.047s)
== 20170307043733-update-users2: migrating =======
== 20170307043733-update-users2: migrated (0.049s)
== 20170308023252-create-profile: migrating =======
== 20170308023252-create-profile: migrated (0.027s)
== 20170308055218-update-users3-link-profile: migrating =======
== 20170308055218-update-users3-link-profile: migrated (0.017s)
$ npm test
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@3.10.10
npm info using node@v6.10.0
npm info lifecycle f-api@0.0.1~pretest: f-api@0.0.1
npm info lifecycle f-api@0.0.1~test: f-api@0.0.1

> f-api@0.0.1 test /builds/f/f-api
> mocha --recursive --timeout 10000

module.js:597
  return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
                 ^

Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 48, got 51.
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:597:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/builds/focus/focus-api/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/builds/focus/focus-api/app/helpers/auth_helper.js:1:78)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/builds/focus/focus-api/config/routes/users.js:4:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/builds/focus/focus-api/config/routes/index.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/builds/focus/focus-api/app.js:8:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/builds/focus/focus-api/test/integration/routes_auth_test.js:1:75)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at /builds/focus/focus-api/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:222:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/builds/focus/focus-api/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:219:14)
    at Mocha.run (/builds/focus/focus-api/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:487:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/builds/focus/focus-api/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:459:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
npm info lifecycle focus-api@0.0.1~test: Failed to exec test script
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

appreciate any pointer to right direction, Thank you for help!!!

Comment: `npm rebuild` --  if not helps then ---
`rm -rf node_modules && npm install`

Comment: <I read this and it seems this is the cause for my issue, because in my local the tests npm test runs fine but in gitlab runner it gives version mismatch issue> When you use version number ranges instead of exact versions there is one important consequence.You can't reproduce the build exactly as it went at a later time. The versions that get installed depend on the time you run npm install.Tomorrow it may install different dependencies than it installs today. This is unsatisfactory for situations where you depend on reproducible.This is the case for production deployments and public releases.

Comment: The reference article which talks about consequences of usage of version number ranges instead of exact versions: https://bytearcher.com/articles/semver-explained-why-theres-a-caret-in-my-package-json/

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: `rm -rf node_modules && yarn`  worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

How are you running the process?

If it might help anyone, we had a similar issues running node via pm2, we were getting this error: Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 48, got 57

It seems the number refers to NODE MODULE version, 48 is node 6, 57 is node 8.

We were running our pm2 processes and each process specifies a particular node version to use. They were point to node 6 versions, even thought our current nvm use version was at 8.12. (node.js version 8.12.0 )

Deleting and restarting the PM2 jobs, created the tasks with the updated link to node 8.12 and we stopped getting that error.

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the versions so npm won't update packages
package-lock will help in this case